# What is the different within jQuery('[id$="myID"]') and $("#<%=myID.ClientID %>")?

Tags: jquery

What is the different within jQuery('[id$="myID"]') and $("#<%=myID.ClientID %>") ?
Which one should be the standard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`jQuery('[id$="myID"]')` - this selects an element which id is ending with `myID`

`$("#<%=myID.ClientID %>")` - this selects an element with `id == myID.ClientID`

As for me I'd prefer the second one, it guarantees that exactly 1 element with the specified id will be selected. If you are sure that you have only one element with id ending with `myID` you can use any of them.

Answer (score 3):

[Attribute Ends With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) `[name$="value"]`

> Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value ending
>   exactly with a given string. The comparison is case sensitive.

[ID Selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) `(“#id”)`

> Selects a single element with the given id attribute.

I suppose the second one should be a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you may using jqote templating plugin.

The first one `jQuery('[id$="myID"]')` is jquery [endsWith](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) selector.

Second one  `$("#<%=myID.ClientID %>")` is just an ID selector. But you may be using `$("#<%=myID.ClientID %>")` in a different place than a typical javascript file. I used to have `<%=....%>` in jqote templating plugin, to embed javascript inside a html template.